# Find all rows which contain a substring within string and return first cells of all such rows in ms-excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have categorized certain ids. Now each id may belong to multiple categories. Let's say column A contains category names, column B has all ids that category contains. I add column C which has all ids ( a single id in a cell). Now i want to have in column D all category names which contain that id(from column C). IF that id is not found among categories(column A) then return "not found".

```
      A             B         C     D

  category A   a21|b43|g87   a21   category A 

  category B   b43|j78|n99   b43   category A category B

                             c35   not found
```

I have tried using Index, Match, iferror, find etc but not able to achieve my intended objective. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Please show the work you have tried doing for pointed suggestions. Ultimately you are trying to extract and concatenate an array of un-known dimensions, something that is nearly impossible to achieve just using formulas. You would likely need to at the very least use a UDF macro to concatenate the array after a conditional formula. Cheers,

Comment: @nbayly  I have tried with =INDEX( $A$2:$A$2,MATCH("*"&C2&"*",$B$2:$B$2,0)) , assuming i have column title of A2. But then i will have to do that for all the categories and still i would be far from what i want. Also =IFERROR(FIND(C2,$B$6),0)>0 gives TRUE or FALSE result. Agree with you that UDF is needed but i don't know how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried a combination of "if" & "search" functions?

For just these two categories and assuming you don't have headers, you can use:

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(C1,B$1)),"",A$1) & " " & IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(C1,B$2)),"",A$2)
```

If you have 3 more categories, you can add them in the same manner (concatenation) while changing the rows for B & A in each if statement. If the ID is not found in any category, it will result in a blank cell. You can add another if statement upfront to return "not found" if it is required, or you can do it manually later by filtering blank cells in column D.

**EDIT:**
If you have too many categories as stated (updated), then best option is to use a short VBA code. The concept is simple: for every ID you have, search all possible categories. Two "for loops" are sufficient.

```
Sub FindID()
 lastRowID = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Define number of IDs
 lastRowCAT = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Define number of CATs

    For i = 2 To lastRowID   'For each ID
        Category = 0         'We reset the category for each ID
        currentID = Range("C" & i).Value 'store the value of the ID

            For j = 2 To lastRowCAT 'Looking the ID in each category
                If InStr(Range("B" & j).Value, currentID) > 0 Then 'If it is found, we add it to cateogries
                   Category = Category & " " & Range("A" & j).Value
                End If
            Next j

            If Category = 0 Then
                Range("D" & i).Value = "not found"
            Else
                Range("D" & i).Value = Right(Category, Len(Category) - 2)
            End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! That works! Only problem is that i have ~1000 such categories and so would need to add those many if statements manually.

Comment: If you have too many categories, then best option is to use a short VBA code.

The concept is simple: for every ID you have, search all possible categories. Two "for loops" are sufficient. 

Somthing like the following will work flawlessly (you can change the defined range last-row to VBA last row function so it automatically detects how many IDs  and categories are there but suppose you have 500 unique IDs, 1000 categories, and  your data have headers):

Comment: For Each Cell in Range ("C2:C501")
   Category = 0
   CurrentRow = cell.Row
   CurrentID = cell.value
   For Each Cell in Range ("B2:B1001")
    
     If " Search cell.Value for CurrentID " returns True Then 'comment: find the syntax for search - you can use worksheet functions with VBA
        Category = cell.offset (0,-1).Value & Category
     End if
 Next Cell

Next Cell

Comment: I am sorry, using my phone. Will modify my answer tomorrow.

Comment: I've modified my answer. It should work now no matter how many categories you have. Regards.

Comment: Thank you very much Ali! That code worked as i wanted. Although i did not have experience in vba but managed to run that code and got the results.